# Switch in multiple custom preference layouts

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a settings activity, HomeActivity, that is loaded on startup. The launch mode is set to singleTask, due to certain requirements, In the layout of the HomeActivity there is an element with a icon, title and a switch. The idea is that you should be able to enable/disable Call, using the switch. And if you click the row (outside the switch) you are brought to a new activity, CallPreferences, where you can set Call specific settings. At the action bar of CallPreferences a switch should also be present where the user again can enable/disable call. Switches on both activites should reflect the "reality". That is, when the switch is changed, the value is stored to shared prefs. Both switches then read from shared prefs onCreate to set their value to on or off.

In the xml of HomeActivity I have a preference screen that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:foo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.xxx.yy" >

    <com.xxx.yy.preferences.IconSwitchPreference
        foo:icon="@drawable/call_icn"        
        android:title="@string/call"
        android:key="callIconSwitchPreference" >
        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:targetClass="com.xxx.yy.preferences.CallPreferences"
            android:targetPackage="om.xxx.yy" />
    </com.xxx.yy.preferences.IconSwitchPreference>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

IconSwitchPreference is a custom preference layout of mine containing a linear layout, a text view for the title, an image view and a switch:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Layout for a Preference in a PreferenceActivity. -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/scrollbarSize">

   <Switch
        android:id="@+id/menu_switch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:onClick="onMenuSwitchClicked" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And the class that runs the code:

```
public class IconSwitchPreference extends IconPreference {

public IconSwitchPreference(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public IconSwitchPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public IconSwitchPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setLayoutResource(R.layout.preference_icon_switch);        
        if (attrs != null) {
            int iconResId = attrs.getAttributeResourceValue(XMLNS, "icon", 0);
            mIcon = context.getResources().getDrawable(iconResId);            
            mFilter = attrs.getAttributeValue(XMLNS, "filter");
            mUrl = attrs.getAttributeValue(XMLNS, "url");
        }
    }   
}
```

In CallPreferences I programmatically create the switch and add it to the action bar:

```
private void createActionBarSwitch() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    Switch actionBarSwitch = new Switch(this);

    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM,
            ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarSwitch, new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL
                    | Gravity.RIGHT));

    actionBarSwitch.setChecked(isSwitchOn());
}
```

This works and I can set the switch to the stored value, and the switch is updated to reflect the value.

In HomeActivity however the switch is *not* updated to reflect the value.

The following does *not* work:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.preference_icon_switch, null);
    TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    tv.setText("Test");
    Switch menuSwitch = (Switch)view.findViewById(R.id.menu_switch);
    menuSwitch.setChecked(sharedPrefs.isCallhandlingEnabled());
}
```

Neither is the text view changed to test, nor is the switch enabled (default value is false).

The following however works:

```
final IconSwitchPreference ic = (IconSwitchPreference) findPreference("callIconSwitchPreference");
ic.setTitle("Test");
```

The title is set to "Test". The only problem is that I don't have any reference to the switch, so I can update it's value. Can IconSwitchPreference.java be updated to extract and store a reference to the switch in its used xml?

I've tried a number of solutions and code samples; but all of them have something that is not working. Another solution would be to use a standard SwitchPreference, but it doesn't differ between a click on the switch itself to change its state (without going to the new activity) and a click on the row to enter the activity (without changing the switch value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by adding the following tag to the HomeActivity xml:

**foo:switchPref="@string/call_enabled_pref_key"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:foo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.xxx.yy" >

    <com.xxx.yy.preferences.IconSwitchPreference
        foo:icon="@drawable/call_icn"        
        android:title="@string/call"
        android:key="callIconSwitchPreference"
        foo:switchPref="@string/call_enabled_pref_key" >
        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:targetClass="com.xxx.yy.preferences.CallPreferences"
            android:targetPackage="om.xxx.yy" />
    </com.xxx.yy.preferences.IconSwitchPreference>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

And then in IconSwitchPreference.java I extract the res id:

**mSwitchPrefResId = attrs.getAttributeResourceValue(XMLNS, "switchPref", 0);**

```
public IconSwitchPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setLayoutResource(R.layout.preference_icon_switch);        
        if (attrs != null) {
            int iconResId = attrs.getAttributeResourceValue(XMLNS, "icon", 0);
            mIcon = context.getResources().getDrawable(iconResId);            
            mFilter = attrs.getAttributeValue(XMLNS, "filter");
            mUrl = attrs.getAttributeValue(XMLNS, "url");
            mSwitchPrefResId = attrs.getAttributeResourceValue(XMLNS, "switchPref", 0);
        }
    }   
}
```

onBindView in the same class (IconSwitchPreference.java) I got a reference to the Switch:

```
@Override
public void onBindView(View view) {
    super.onBindView(view);
    mSwitch = (Switch) view.findViewById(R.id.menu_switch);
    updateSwitch();
}
```

Then I used mSwitchPrefResId to fetch the shared prefs (to know if the switch is enabled or not) and set mSwitch to the corresponding value.